# Can we upgrade PowerPC Macs to OS X 10.7 now that 10.8 is out?

Tags: macos, upgrade, powerpc, processor

I know that 10.8 is out now, but we have older Macs that will not work under 10.8, **as they do not have Intel processors**. Can we still buy and get 10.7, which I believe will support older CPUs?

Comment: What operating system are you currently running? What happens when you open the Mac App store? What model Mac do you have?

Comment: If your Mac is so old that it doesn't have an Intel processor, it won't run anything more recent than Mac OS X 10.5 (Leopard). Mac OS X 10.5 was the last major upgrade that supports PowerPC processors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this topic popped up again, several months later, I'll add a quick and impolite answer:

**No, you cannot install 10.7 on any Mac that does not have an Intel processor.**

**All releases of OS X starting with 10.6 require Intel processors.**

Answer (score 11):

If your attempting to upgrade a PowerPC Mac the most you can upgrade one of those is [Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Leopard), since it was the last version of OS X to support PowerPC processors.

**So the answer is no to upgrading to any OS beyond Mac OS X 10.5 if the Mac your trying to upgrade is has a PowerPC processor.**

If you have an Intel Mac that support OS X Lion and you really want Lion or if Lion is the last version of OS X that your Mac can run, you will be able to contact Apple and arrange a way to purchase it via Apple's legacy products list as noted in the following MacWorld article: [Apple pulls Lion from the Mac App Store](http://www.macworld.com/article/1167879/apple_pulls_lion_from_the_mac_app_store.html)

> ...while Lion is no longer available for sale from the Mac App Store, customers can still purchase it from the legacy products list via Apple phone sales.

So if you really want lion contact Apple at **1-800-MY-APPLE** and let them know you want to order OS X Lion.

Comment: Yes, you can call them and order it, I tested this out, see my answer for the details and price.

Comment: I didn't down vote you.

Comment: Not saying you did just trying to get feedback from those who did, in order to improve or remove the answers as needed.

Answer (score 7):

Although you can no longer buy Lion through the App Store or directly by SKU from the online store, you can still order Lion after Mountain Lion was released.

I called 1-800-MY-APPLE, it took some time to get through but they told me that I would be able to purchase Lion, OS X 10.7 from them for $19.99.  They would send me the physical copy through the mail.

*Be careful to understand the return policy* if you are not certain your Mac can run Lion. OS X Lion 10.7 is only supported on Intel Processors, Intel Core 2 Duo and higher and **Lion will not work on PowerPC (PPC) Macs**.

I hope that my answer helps you out. Thanks for @DanielLawson for the push.

Comment: Where did you get this information? I'm looking for reports of what happens when one visits the App store with a machine that supports Lion but not Snow Leopard.

Comment: The Lion USB stick was sold in the physical Apple Stores in addition to online.

Comment: @DanielLawson Here is the article that states that Lion has been pulled for purchase from the App Store: http://www.macworld.com/article/1167879/apple_pulls_lion_from_the_mac_app_store.html You can still redownload it if you already purchased it, but for those looking to buy it is unavailable for purchase.

Comment: In that article, Macworld reports "In response to our query on the matter, Apple spokesperson Monica Sarkar told Macworld that, while Lion is no longer available for sale from the Mac App Store, customers can still purchase it from the legacy products list via Apple phone sales. But when we called 1-800-MY-APPLE, sales representatives there said Lion was not available. It may well be that, if there is a Lion legacy-sales program, it has not yet been communicated to the sales reps." So it might be premature to say there is no way to buy Lion from Apple.

Comment: @DanielLawson, Ok, I'll call them and see if the program has been updated yet and if we can now buy Lion through them.

Comment: If not, this is a major failure of the system!

Comment: @DanielLawson Ok, after being on hold with Apple for about 10 minutes, I was able to get through until for some reason my call was cut off, but before that I was able to get an answer.  They said that I could purchase Lion through them for 29.99. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Why the down vote? Any feedback is welcome so I can make my answers better.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, meant to say: "You can run PPC apps from Snow Leopard 10.6 actually with Rosetta":

"Snow Leopard only supported machines with Intel CPUs, required at least 1 GB of RAM, and dropped default support for applications built for the PowerPC architecture (Rosetta could be installed as an additional component to retain support for PowerPC-only applications).[97]"

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X#Version_10.5:_.22Leopard.22

Comment: How does this differ from other previous answers?

Answer (score -1):

What good can the newest Mac OSX do if it can not be installed on a DuoCore Power PC with 16 GB of RAM. Apple is full of it....I won't spend a single dime on Apple products. I got robbed by Apple about $3000.00 a few years ago. I actually found an iPhone 4s and gave it away.

Comment: Would you be able to back up the robbery with some details? Did they hold you up or not publish information you needed to make a proper decision or in what way were you harmed by "the man"?